# Core Plot: RealTimePlot - put static yAxis

Tags: objective-c, ios5, static, core-plot

My problem is that i cant put static yAxis (without movement) in my example of RealTimePlot. 
During movement xAxis are static but yAxis disappear.

My code is:

```
-(void)renderInLayer:(CPTGraphHostingView *)layerHostingView withTheme:(CPTTheme *)theme
{

    graph = [[[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:bounds] autorelease];
    layerHostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop    = 15.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight  = 15.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 55.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft   = 55.0;

    // Axes
    // X axis
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0);
    x.minorTicksPerInterval       = 9;
    x.title                       = @"X Axis";
    x.titleOffset                 = 35.0;

    // Y axis
    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0);
    y.minorTicksPerInterval       = 3;
    y.labelOffset                 = 5.0;
    y.title                       = @"Y Axis";
    y.titleOffset                 = 30.0;

    y.constraints = CPTMakeConstraints(CPTConstraintNone, CPTConstraintFixed);

    // Rotate the labels by 45 degrees, just to show it can be done.
    x.labelRotation = M_PI * 0.25;

    // Create the plot
    CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
    dataSourceLinePlot.identifier     = kPlotIdentifier;
    dataSourceLinePlot.cachePrecision = CPTPlotCachePrecisionDouble;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [[dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];
    lineStyle.lineWidth              = 3.0;
    lineStyle.lineColor              = [CPTColor greenColor];
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

    dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
    [graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];
```

}

My version of CorePlot is 1.0.

Any idea??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `constraints` syntax changed before the 1.0 release. Try

```
y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```

Comment: It´s impossible use this line in Core Plot 1.0, is deprecated!!

Comment: No, it's not. The `CPTMakeConstraints` function was removed at the same time the `CPTConstraints` class was added. This change was made before the 0.9 release, so you must not be using the 1.0 release package. See the Core Plot change log (http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/changelog.txt) and the change details here: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/detail?r=2926326f8a54eb0b82f5444abf3616cc714758d7

Comment: oK, This code dont have errors:  y.constraints = CPTMakeConstraints(CPTConstraintNone, CPTConstraintFixed); or  y.constraints = CPTMakeConstraints(CPTConstraintNone, CPTConstraintNone); but the result dont found.... yAxi dissappear when the movement advancing.

Comment: Make sure your app references the correct Core Plot library and headers. The `CPTMakeConstraints()` function does not exist in 1.0 and should cause compiler errors.